# Categorizing polygons instead of using default single symbol in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

Is there any way to change display polygon from single symbol (default setting) to categorize?

So far, when I added a feature polygon into the table of contain, it will be displayed as only one symbol, but now I would like to have it always displays as category automatically without manually changing.

[image]

The default setting:

[image]

What it should be

Comment: So is it different source data that you add each time, or the same feature class? If same, you can use a layer file to preserve symbology when adding next time. If not, is it always the same field (with the same values) that you want to categorize from?

Comment: Can you use the edit button to explain your use case in more detail, please?  Is this for when you add a new layer, and open its properties to the symbology tab for the first time?